# Meteor: Deps.autorun not triggered when updating a collection

Tags: meteor

On the client I have this:

```
var Coll1 = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection1');
var Coll2 = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection2');

var handle1 = null;
Deps.autorun(function () {
    var temp = Session.get('id');
    if (id) handle1 = Meteor.subscribe('myCollection1', id);
};

var handle2 = null;
Deps.autorun(function () {
    var temp = Session.get('id');
    if (id) handle2 = Meteor.subscribe('myCollection2', id);
};
```

And elsewhere in a template code, I do this (when the user clicks on an DOM element):

```
Coll1.insert({name: 'new element1');
Coll2.insert({name: 'new element2');
```

The above code does not trigger an update of Coll1 and Coll2 in the client (but well on the server). If I refresh my browser, the update is performed, i.e., the client syncs up with the server and displays the new elements.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont appear to be changing the reactive variable here `Session.get('id')`

Deps.autorun works like so

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  var iAmReactive = Session.get('iAmReactive');
  <subscribe to something using iAmReactive>
});
```

if session value for `iAmReactive` changes, the subscription is re-run

also this could be something like

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  var iAmAReactiveQuery = Collection.find({<query>});
  <subscribe to something>
});
```

in this case if the data in the query changes, the subscription is rerun

---

what does the publish function look like?  are you sure the inserted items are returned with the supplied id parameter?

Comment: OK, I thought that `Meteor.subscribe()` or the `handles` were themselves reactive sources and would trigger an update when the collection changes (through the `insert`), but it seems not. How could I trigger the re-run of the `Deps.autorun()`functions after the insert?

Comment: for your code you just need to set the session var - eg `Session.set('id', somethingNew)` - take a hard look at http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity - its fairly well laid out there about what will cause a reactive computation (deps.autorun) to re-run